# Amazon connect call one to one contact flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am developing an application where I can initiate calls using an Amazon Connect phone number using PHP. Placing the call is successful, but I am encountering challenges with designing a contact flow. Specifically, I want a simple one-to-one call without any audio prompts or intermediary actions between the two parties. I have attempted to omit the contact flow ID from the code, but it is flagged as a required parameter. I am seeking guidance on how to design the contact flow to achieve a straightforward call where the receiving party answers and the conversation begins without any automated prompts or agent interaction.

This is the contact flow design currently below

[image]

Comment: What are your requirements? Make a list to form a better understanding of the job. What are other constraints? As it stands, your question is way too broad to answer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt what I want is I want to place a call to any person without any recording placed between it. I mean just like a regular call we place in our daily lives through sim. So for example I am building this application for myself so I can call my friends living abroad using amazon number. Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are four flows you need to deliver the call to an agent in Connect.

The inbound flow, you set the queue that the call is going to go through and define what "customer queue" flow to use. This is where your created outbound call will be sent.

The customer queue flow where you define what the caller hears while waiting in queue. You can have silence played, but this flow needs to exist and be called.

Then the agent and customer whisper flows that define what is played to the agent and caller immediately prior to the call being connected. You can play nothing.

Only once the call has gone through these flows will it be presented to an agent with a routing profile that includes the queue.

But I'm not sure why you'd do all this just to call some people. Why not just log into the CCP as an agent and make calls?

Comment: I am building an application and I want to do it programmatically